# SQL - ORDER BY Works in Sub-query, But Fails in Full Query

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to set up a dynamic query to populate average payments over a dynamic period of months. I have a working query, but it provides the months out of order.

I assign the months to a variable, @columns, and use that in the main query to determine the fields for a PIVOT command. The following is how the variable is set up;

[image: Full assigment query]

As can be seen, the months are out of order.

But, if I run just the sub-query;

[image]

It orders fine.

What's going on? Any thoughts?

Thanx in advance!

(hopefully, the images come out as I want)

Comment: why are you using images?  images make it hard to answer your question for many reasons.  do you want people to answer your question?  why make it hard?

Comment: Please add code and examples in text not images

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: @Hogan Op is new, he probably doesn't know the way around, try to  give him some advice instead

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- I did?

Comment: I think they mean copy and paste the text, not do screenshots.  As for the problem- can you instead do the `order by` in the outer query?

Comment: Apologies for the screen shots, but I wanted to include the output and how it looked. I thought the screenshots would be the most accurate way to do that.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  _SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your examples are invalid standard SQL

Comment: I'm using SSMS. The examples have the error lines, because I need to conceal the database sources. So, the DB names are pseudo-code, however, with the real DB names used, the output shown is the actual results set.

Answer (score 1):

In your outer select you need to specify `ORDER BY` to guarantee the order. Currently you are only ordering your derived table and not the final query.

```
SELECT @columns += ',' + QUOTENAME(Eff_Period)
FROM
  (derived table) AS Raw_Data
ORDER BY Eff_Period

PRINT @columns
```

Comment: In case you're wondering what in blue blazes is going on with this question, SELECT TOP 100% ORDER BY used to dupe the SQL optimizer into actually doing it, even inside a view. It wasn't reliable, but if only loop joins came after the subquery expansion it would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT @columns == ',' + QUOTENAME (Eff_period)
 FROM ( ... ) as Raw_Data
 ORDER BY Eff_period
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the subquery is unnecessary if all you need additionally is to concatenate the text `',' + + QUOTENAME(Eff_Period)`.  But you can just do this without a subquery.  Also, the `TOP 100 PERCENT` does not work as others have pointed out, it's not needed in any case.

```
SELECT @column += ',' + QUOTENAME(Eff_Period)
  FROM Members_Data AS Mbrs
       INNER JOIN Claims_Data AS Clms
        ON Mbrs.Eff_Period = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(7), Clms.Date_of_Service, 121), '-', '')
 WHERE YEAR(Clms.Date_of_Service) = 2016

GROUP BY Mbrs.Eff_Period
ORDER BY Eff_Period
```

Also... I had to re-type the entire text from the screenshot.  Not a big deal to some people, but this is one reason we prefer the text versus screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the outside **ORDER BY** was the answer.

I thought **ORDER BY** had to use field names and, as there was none, I had no clue how to put it in there. I tried using the ordinal, 1, unfortunately that only gave me the final value in the concatenated list.

But, it appears that it can take **Eff_Period** in the outside **SELECT**; perhaps because it's a unique name from the **JOIN**.

However, that answered the problem I was having. A problem that arose from an answer that I thought fixed an overlying problem, but I have discovered does not. I'm trying to figure that out at this time.

Thanx to everyone who responded!